# How could I display a non-image file stored in MongoDB(using GridFS) on a web page?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, gridfs, multer-gridfs-storage

I am working on a site that allows a user to upload a document (not an image), which is then stored in MongoDB with GridFS. My question is... is it possible to then embed/display that document for viewing on the site? Everytime I use the `createReadStream` method, it just downloads the document. I would like it to show the actual document or the document's contents on the webpage, possibly in an iframe. Maybe there is a way to make a url for the document, or access the file another way? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2):

```
<ifram
```

```html
 <iframe src= 'https://www.vanmeegern.de/fileadmin/user_upload/PDF/Web_Development_with_Node_Express.pdf' frameborder="0" width="400px" height="600px"></iframe>
```

e>

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).